# php interface union type for method argument

Tags: php, interface

I have an interface and two classes that implement it. For one method in the interface the two implementations require different arguments. One way to do it would be to either use no type at all or a union type. Both feel wrong.

```
class OptionsA {
    public string $someSpecificOptionForA;
    public int $anotherSpecificOptionForA;
    ...

}

class OptionsB {
    public bool $someSpecificOptionForB;
    ...

}

interface InteractsWithQueue {
    public function getNextEntry(OptionsA|OptionsB $options) : QueueEntry;
}

class ProcessorA implements InteractsWithQueue {
      public function getNextEntry(OptionsA|OptionsB $options) : QueueEntry {...}
}

class ProcessorB implements InteractsWithQueue {
      public function getNextEntry(OptionsA|OptionsB $options) : QueueEntry {...}
}
```

Comment: Maybe have both `OptionsA` and `OptionsB` implement some interface, eg `QueueOptions`.  Then you could type hint your `InteractsWithQueue` interface with that new interface instead

Comment: @RobEyre you mean an empty interface? then I won't get any autocompletion anymore

Comment: if necessary, yes.  Although if really `OptionsA` and `OptionsB` have very little in common I would question why you need to have `getNextEntry()` in your `InteractsWithQueue` interface at all.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces is about behaviour, not about state of the object. Based on this, may be such solution will suitable:

```
 <?php

class QueueEntry {
    public string $text;
    
    
}

class OptionsA {
    public string $someSpecificOptionForA;
    public int $anotherSpecificOptionForA;
}

class OptionsB {
    public bool $someSpecificOptionForB;
}

interface InteractsWithQueue {
    public function getNextEntry() : QueueEntry;
}

class ProcessorA implements InteractsWithQueue {
      private OptionsA $options;

      public function setOptions(OptionsA $options) {
        $this->options = $options;
      }

      public function getNextEntry() : QueueEntry {
          $qe = new QueueEntry;
          $qe->text = "ProcessorA Entry";
          return $qe;
      }
}

class ProcessorB implements InteractsWithQueue {
      private OptionsB $options;

      public function setOptions(OptionsB $options) {
        $this->options = $options;
      }

      public function getNextEntry() : QueueEntry {
          $qe = new QueueEntry;
          $qe->text = "ProcessorB Entry";
          return $qe;
      }
}

class EntityA {
    public function getProcessor(OptionsA $options) : InteractsWithQueue {
        $processor = new ProcessorA;
        $processor->setOptions($options);
        return $processor;
    }
}

class EntityB {
     public function getProcessor(OptionsB $options) : InteractsWithQueue {
        $processor = new ProcessorB;
        $processor->setOptions($options);
        return $processor;
    }
}

$a = new EntityA;
$optsA = new OptionsA;
$a->getProcessor($optsA);
var_dump($a->getProcessor($optsA)->getNextEntry());

$b = new EntityB;
$optsB = new OptionsB;
var_dump($b->getProcessor($optsB)->getNextEntry());
```